# Why does Inline Code not show up in RMarkdown?

Tags: rstudio

I am trying to input some inline code in RStudio but it's not working.

All the resources I have looked up simply say to put   around the text that I want to present as inline code.
It shows up just fine here on Stackoverflow, but when I knit the Rmd file, it just shows up as normal text.
Example:
When I type
"The `:` operator"
into RStudio and knit it, it appears as
"The : operator"
If anyone can point out what I missed, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please add the code you are using, or at least the part that is at issue, to your question. It will make it easier to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if that counts as code. I am literally trying to get the words, "The `:` operator..." in my RMarkdown. But instead of the colon symbol becoming inline code as seen in my question, it appears as "The : operator..."
I hope that clears it up.